# mysql: sub-query makes global query much slower than just using the sub-query's actual results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables in a mysql database:

1. articles - has a numerical AUTO_INCREMENT id field, and some text fields using fulltext indexes
2. categories - has a numerical AUTO_INCREMENT id field, and some other fields that are not relevant
3. articles_categories - connects articles to categoties using two foreign keys: article_id (pointing to the id field of articles), and category_id (pointing to the id field of categories)

Now, I'm running the following query:

```
select AC.category_id, count(*) as num_articles
from categories C
join articles_categories AC on C.id = AC.category_id
where AC.article_id in (
select id from articles where match(name, teaser, plaintext_contents) against ('some text' in boolean mode)
)
group by AC.category_id;
```

, and it's taking almost 3 seconds to run with several hunders of fields in each table. Here are the results of running this query with EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  C   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       187 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  AC  ref IX_articles_categories_category_id_article_id   IX_articles_categories_category_id_article_id   4   kalir_co_il.C.id    56  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  articles    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   kalir_co_il.AC.article_id   1   Using index condition; Using where
```

But here's the oddity.

The following subquery running in the middle of my query only takes 0.4 seconds:

```
select id from articles where match(name, teaser, plaintext_contents) against ('some text' in boolean mode)
```

so I'm thinking the rest of the query is what takes so long. But... when I replace the sub-query with its actual results, which are a list of 27 ids (numbers), I run the entire query, and it executes in less than 0.1 seconds!

```
select AC.category_id, count(*) as num_articles
from categories C
join articles_categories AC on C.id = AC.category_id
where AC.article_id in (61,
167,
352,
374,
407,
419,
455,
462,
467,
502,
575,
696,
746,
756,
759,
851,
1001,
1046,
1052,
1311,
1497,
1501,
1502,
1503,
1508,
1514,
1538
)
group by AC.category_id;
```

with the following results from EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  C   index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       187 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  AC  ref IX_articles_categories_category_id_article_id   IX_articles_categories_category_id_article_id   4   kalir_co_il.C.id    56  Using where; Using index
```

How does this make sense?

Note: I'm hoping to avoid posting actual table and index code, but I'll do it if I have to. Thanks to anyone willing to help...

Comment: Hard for us to recommend query optimization steps without understanding the table definitions (particularly the indexes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql's has a history of not handling subqueries amazingly well. There are a lot of intricacies that can play a role in this depending on your mysql version, flags etc. Take a look at this document for details - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html

Also, have you tried rewriting your query as a join instead?

```
select AC.category_id, count(*) as num_articles
from categories C
join articles_categories AC on C.id = AC.category_id
join (
  select id from articles where match(name, teaser, plaintext_contents) against ('some text' in boolean mode)
) A_IDS ON A_IDS.id=AC.article_id

group by AC.category_id;
```

What does the performance look like then?

Comment: I'll read that article later, it sounds quite interesting. But you, my friend - are a genius! the query is now 6 times faster! thank you so much!